# Getting System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed but cannot fix it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis

I have read many blogs and many questions here among stacks, but could not find my exact scenario (which is very simple one actually).

### Context

I have a service written inside a library in a Visual Studio 2010 project. The i wrote the interface for the service contract and the service class implementing that contract.

```
namespace MyNS.WebSrvLibrary {
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.dummy.com")]
public interface IEchoService {
  [OperationContract()]
  EchoMessageResponse Echo(EchoMessage msg);
}
}
```

The service:

```
namespace MyNS.WebSrvLibrary {
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class EchoService : IEchoService {
  public EchoService() {}
  [OperationBehavior()]
  public virtual EchoMessageResponse Echo(EchoMessage msg) {
    return new EchoMessageResponse("Ciccio");
  }
  public static IEchoService GetChannel(string addr = "") {
    // Create the service endpoint
    Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint =
      new ServiceEndpoint(
            ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IEchoService)),
            binding,
            new EndpointAddress(addr));
    // Create channel factory and get proper channel for service.
    ChannelFactory<IEchoService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoService>(endpoint);
    IEchoService svc = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    return svc;
  }
}
}
```

Classes like `EchoMessageResponse` and `EchoMessage` have `DataContract`s applied and they are ok.

The service as I said before is compiled into a dll (assembly) that i import into a web application in the bin folder just by adding a reference. In this web application I have the `svc` file for the web service:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyNS.WebSrvLibrary.EchoService" %>
```

And this is the `Web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyNS.WebSrvLibrary.EchoService">
        <endpoint name="basicHttpBinding" address="" 
                                     binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                                     bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_Svc"
                                     contract="MyNS.WebSrvLibrary.IEchoService"/>
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="/Mex"
                                     binding="mexHttpBinding"
                                     contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" closeTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="12:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1310720"
                        maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="24096"
                        maxDepth="10000"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_Svc" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" closeTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="12:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1310720"
                        maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="24096"
                        maxDepth="10000"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So, finally, I have a client application compiling to an executable `.exe` file which is the following:

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    IEchoService svc = EchoService.GetChannel("http://localhost:80/T/Service.svc");
    EchoMessageResponse rmsp = svc.Echo(new EchoMessage("Hello"));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
  } /* Main */
} /* Program */
```

#### Information on server-side matters

The web application is hosted in IIS in the *Default Web Site* listening to port 80 of course.

### The problem

When I run my executable application, I get this `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   `http://localhost/T/Service.svc`. This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due
>   to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due
>   to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Whose `innerException` is of type: `System.Net.WebException`:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Whose `innerException` (the last in the exception tree) is of type `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The complete stack is the following:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   DDBR.DiscoveryServiceLibrary.IEchoService.Echo(EchoMessage msg)    at
>   DDBR.TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Data\ROOT_APPS\DistributedDataBackupAndRecovery\TestClient\Program.cs:line
>   20    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Which can be found in the `StackTrace` property of the first exception (the initial one, not the inner ones).

#### Something very strange...

The very strange thing is that if I open my browser and type:

```
http://localhost/T/Service.svc
```

I get the famous screen my Microsoft IIS that exposes some basic info about the service. This means that the web service is alive and running at the specified address (endpoint).

I looked for this exception but no one has these peculiarities... generally a more detailed and complex context is involved.

What to do?

### One thing more...

You are probably wondering why I do not use service references... Because I do not want to. There are reasons for this. The point here is that the `GetChannel` approach has always worked with me so far... do not understand why I have problems now...

Actually what kind of problem is it supposed to be? It cannot be timeout really do not believe this, it is a simple method acting in the fastest of the many possible ways. It is strange... really.

Comment: Quick question out of the context --> how did you manage to get the EchoService class reference in your client program?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a service reference to your console app and use the proxy object and not the actual service class that you are using.  You are using the service as a client. Instead of calling the service through the auto generated proxy classes that get created when you add a service reference to your client project.

Comment: This thing of the proxy is something I do not really like... The GetChannel stuff is something I tried before and has always worked... I do not understand why now it is not working...

Comment: Well you are explicitly creating an instance of the service and trying to call it. It isn't hosted the way your example describes it. You will still have the GetChannel method on the proxy.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by "it isn't hosted the way your example describes it". Do not think I am being arrogant please, if I have a problem now is because I am making some mistake... With this approach I simple get an instance of my service which is represented by an objected which is returned as the Interface representing the contract. The getchannel stuff will simply create the endpoint and return it. So I have a connection to my web service. I also know that this is done by the proxy, but I want to do it manually, that's all...

Comment: I could very much be mistaken. It is early and I'm not a WCF expert, just looked odd to me that is all. No offense intended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a `DataContract` related one. In one of my classes that I use as messages to be passed to service methods, I had a property miswritten that caused the serializer to experience loops... This caused `StackOverflow Exception` which caused the serializer to go Berserk and the connection to be closed.

I thought the problem was not a data related one and did not provide the code for this. Sorry for bothering guys. At least my question could provide some useful info regarding errors in `DataContracts` but that one cannot really grasp by looking at the exception description.